# S3 subdomain endpoint access URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

S3 Bucket URL is accessible with: bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

But not accessible with: s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/index.html

See this working example: https://s3.amazonaws.com/crazygames-unblocked/index.html

And its also accessible with https://crazygames-unblocked.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

How do I achieve this?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/

Answer (score 0):

There are (were) **two styles** to [reference buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro):

- **Virtual hosted** style: such as `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html`
- **Path style** style: such as `s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/index.html`

Path style is [no longer supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro):

> Buckets created after September 30, 2020, will **support only virtual hosted-style requests**.

This means that in your case only `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html` will be supported, on the assumption that this is a new bucket.